# Oracle/PLSQL nested for loop for inserting values

Tags: oracle, plsql

I get the error

> ORA-00984: column not allowed here

when I run this PLSQL script:

```
BEGIN
    FOR i IN (
        SELECT attribute_id
        FROM odd_attribute
    ) LOOP
        FOR j IN (
            SELECT t1.sourceattribute_id
            FROM odd_sourceattribute t1
            WHERE t1.sourcetable_id IN (
                SELECT t2.sourcetable_id
                FROM odd_sourcetable t2
                WHERE t2.sourcetable_name LIKE 'vr_db_f_%'
            )
        ) LOOP
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'insert into odd_fact_attribute 
                          (attribute_id, sourceattribute_id, statusattribute_name, other_stuff_to_describe_fact) 
                          values 
                          (i.attribute_id, j.sourceattribute_id, NULL, NULL)'
            ;
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

The column names seems to be correct and I'm not able to figure out the cause of the error. Appreciate all the help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error was raised because you are referring to the column names from implicit cursor within quotes of `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`, which are going to be treated as table references in static sql.

You may avoid that with the help of placeholders (starting with `:` ) and a `USING` statement.

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
'INSERT INTO odd_fact_attribute (
        attribute_id,
        sourceattribute_id,
        statusattribute_name,
        other_stuff_to_describe_fact
    ) VALUES (
        :attribute_id,
        :sourceattribute_id,
        NULL,
        NULL
    )'
    USING i.attribute_id,j.sourceattribute_id;
```

Importantly, there is no need of `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` and your PL/SQL block with nested loop is equivalent to a single `INSERT` statement like this, which is going to be much efficient than your loops.

```
INSERT INTO odd_fact_attribute (
    attribute_id,
    sourceattribute_id,
    statusattribute_name,
    other_stuff_to_describe_fact
)
    SELECT o.attribute_id,
           t1.sourceattribute_id,
           NULL,
           NULL
    FROM odd_sourceattribute t1
    CROSS JOIN odd_attribute o --use appropriate join condn. if this is not the case
    WHERE t1.sourcetable_id IN (
        SELECT t2.sourcetable_id
        FROM odd_sourcetable t2
        WHERE t2.sourcetable_name LIKE 'vr_db_f_%'
    );
```

Comment: The second option works perfectly. The first option took more than one hour to execute because the expected output consists of around 900,000 rows. Therefore I just terminated it and tried the second option which took about 2 seconds. Lesson learnt: use queries if possible instead of loops! Thank you so much.